# POST-запрос при клике на ссылку

Tags: php, javascript

Раньше была кнопка, при нажатии на которую переменная $sec передавалась на другую страницу. Теперь у меня ссылки и необходимо сделать то же самое. Я предполагаю, что можно это сделать с помощью `hidden` поля. Может быть есть другие способы?

```php
include('set.php');

echo "<form method='post' action='obj.php'>";

$sql = mysql_query("select * from `obj`  order by `id`");

for ($i = 1; $i <= mysql_num_rows($sql); $i++) {
  while ($s = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo '<a href="obj.php">"<img src='.$s['img'].
      '>'.$s['id'].
      '</a>';
  }
  $sec = $s['id'];
}

echo "</form>";
```

Comment: Вопрос по `javascript`, а не по `php`. Можете обрабатывать клик по ссылке, заполнять `hidden` поле и делать `submit` формы. Или же вы можете воспользоваться методом `post` библиотеки `jQuery`.

Comment: @Pyramidhead а если я с js не дружу,то как быть?

Comment: Например, использовать `GET` вместо `POST`. И, соответственно, ссылки вида `<a href="obj.php?sec=значение">содержимое ссылки</a>`.

Comment: @Pyramidhead т,е так     echo  '<a href="obj.php?sec='.$s['id'].'">"<img src='.$s['img'].'>'.$s['id'].'</a>';

Comment: @Pyramidhead ах да чуть не забыл мне важно чтоб в переменную передавалось

Comment: Да, так. Но `obj.php` должен обрабатывать `$_GET['sec']`.

Comment: @Pyramidhead все получилось спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вариант 1:**

Добавить обработчик `onclick` для ссылок, который будет заполнять `hidden` поле и делать `submit` формы.

javascript:

```
function doSubmit(val) {
  document.getElementById("sec").value = val;
  document.forms["form_id"].submit();
  return false;
}
```

jquery:

```
function doSubmit(val) {
  $("#sec").val(val);
  $("#form_id").submit();
  return false;
}
```

**Вариант 2:**

Использовать метод `post` библиотеки `jQuery` (подходит, если не нужен переход на другую страницу)

```
$.post( 'obj.php', { sec: val } );
```

**Вариант 3:**

Использовать `GET` вместо `POST`. То есть ссылки будут иметь вид

```
<a href="obj.php?sec=значение">содержимое ссылки</a>
```

а сам `obj.php` сможет получить значение из глобального массива: `$_GET['sec']`.